# Python Versions Performance

Tags: python, performance, benchmarking, versions

Where I can find a comparative speed benchmark between python versions?

For example the performance between 2.6, 2.7, 3.0 , 3.1 and 3.2 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pystone benchmark on 2.6,2.7,3.2:

- [http://www.levigross.com/post/2340736877/pystone-benchmark-on-2-6-2-7-3-2](http://web.archive.org/web/20130805083640/http://www.levigross.com/post/2340736877/pystone-benchmark-on-2-6-2-7-3-2)

(3.0 and 3.1 are probably [slower than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170426/python-3-performance) 3.2)

Comment: Is this "pystone" good for benchmarks?(or there is an official speed comparison?) Thank you anyways ;)

Comment: Hmm the URL levigross,com is dead. Can you link to a cached version, or else something else?

Answer (score 4):

The Python Software Foundation hosts a speed comparison site at https://speed.python.org/comparison/ that provides an overview of different benchmarks.

Currently, it only includes CPython versions (that are still supported) but PyPy has a similar site available at: https://speed.pypy.org/comparison/

Answer (score 1):

There is a Python module with various real-world performance tasks to measure different builds / versions of Python - [`performance`](https://pyperformance.readthedocs.io).

You can install it with the following command:

```
pip install pyperformance
```

And run it with the following one to compare Python2 and Python3 on your system:

```
pyperformance run --python=python2 -o py2.json
pyperformance run --python=python3 -o py3.json
pyperformance compare py2.json py3.json
```

Comment: I get this error after installation: `pyperformance: command not found`

Comment: try `pip install pyperformance` instead